# rosalind solution fixing: shared motifs

Tags: python, longest-substring, rosalind

I am aware that there are solutions for rosalind challenges but I do not want them to spoil the fun. I thought I found a solution for "Finding a shared motif" yet my answer is wrong all the time.

The question is about finding the longest common substring(s) in a given sheet which is made of a line starting with ">" and the next lines until another line starting with a ">" are composing a sequence. here is how it looks like:

```
>Rosalind_1
GATTACA
>Rosalind_2
TAGACCA
>Rosalind_3
ATACA
```

There are like a hundred dna pieces and you are to find to longest common subsequence. Here is my approach:

```
    rosa = open("rosalind_lcsm.txt","r")
    oku = rosa.readlines()
    strs=[]
    for line in oku:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            strs.append("kiko")
        else:
            strs.append(line)
    rosa.close()
    strs = strs[1:]
    joint = "".join(strs)
    joint_s = joint.split("kiko")

    theOne = joint_s[0]
    rest = joint_s[1:]

    start=0
    end=1
    matches=[]

    while end < len(theOne):
        end+=1
        while all(theOne[start:end] in seq for seq in rest):
            end+=1
        else:
            matches.append(theOne[start:end-1])
            end+=1
        start=end-1
    print(max(matches, key=len))
```

My strategy was as; read the file, split it into sequences, pick the first sequence and compare its common parts to the rest. I am checking minimum 2 matches as the sequences are made of ATGC and 1 match will definitely occur. It starts from a character and keeps on expanding it by 1 characters until the match is broken. Then it takes the last matching bit and appends into a list. Then restarts from where it stopped.

My solution gives an answer yet it is not the right one and I cannot spot the misleading part in the code. Can someone try to understand my approach and give me an advice on fixing it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't speak python, but I think you're skipping possible matches by doing `start=end-1`. You probably need to do `start=start+1`.

For example, let's say you have these strings:

GATCAA
GAGCAATCAA

Your algorithm will first find GA as common substring, and then continue looking from the third character. But that way you're missing the real longest common substring, ATCAA.

**EDIT:** Obviously you also need to reinitialize `end` together with `start`. Either you set it to `start+1` to always start looking from a two-letter string like you're doing, or you can optimize your code by starting from the length of the longest match you've found so far.